# Jenkins Pipeline & Docker Plugin - concurrent builds on unique agents

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, agent

I'm using Jenkins version 2.7.1 with the Pipeline suite of plugins to implement a pipeline in a Jenkinsfile, together with the Docker Plugin. My goal is to execute multiple project builds in parallel, with each project build running inside its own dedicated container. My Jenkinsfile looks like:

```
node('docker-agent') {
    stage('Checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }

    stage('Setup') {
        build(job: 'Some External Job', node: env.NODE_NAME, workspace: env.WORKSPACE)
    }
}
```

I have a requirement to call an external job, but I need this to execute on the same workspace where the `checkout scm` step has checked out the code, hence the `node` and `workspace` parameters. I understand that by wrapping a `build` call inside a `node` block effectively wastes an executor, but I'm fine with that since the agent is a container on a Docker Cloud and isn't really wasting any resources.

The one problem with my approach is that another instance of this project build could steal the executors from a different running instance in the time gap between the 2 stages.

How can I essentially ensure that (1) project builds can run concurrently, but (2) each build runs on a new instance of an agent labelled by `docker-agent`?

I've tried the Locking plugin, but a new build will simply wait to acquire the lock on existing agent rather than spinning up its own agent.

Comment: what about using multiple agents with 1 executor each? What's the build doing? I usually use docker-compose for my pipelines, which allows me to accomplish `My goal is to execute multiple project builds in parallel, with each project build running inside its own dedicated container.`

Answer (score 0):

To prevent other builds running on the same agent, limit the number of executors to 1 for each agent in your docker cloud environment (that's a setting when configuring docker for that label). That will require a new container to start per executor.

That said, I wouldn't design a pipeline like this. Instead, I'd use [stash](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) and [unstash](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-unstash-code-restore-files-previously-stashed) to copy your checkout and any other small artifacts between the nodes so that you can pause execution without holding a node running.